# Specific Asymptotic Function

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-geometry

I asked a similar question yesterday, but I wasn't very clear and/or I don't understand how the answer given met my conditions.

I want a function that takes elements of $\mathbb R$ to other elements of $\mathbb R$ such that:

(i) For every $x \in \mathbb R, f(x) < x$, and $f(x) \in \mathbb R$

(ii) $f(x)$ asymptotically approaches some chosen positive limit $L$ as $x \to \infty$

One answer given was that I could take the function $f(x) = ex^{-x}$ and then use $g(x) = f(x - L) + L$ as my function. However, I don't see how, for instance, if my limit is 100 and x = 10, it satisfies those conditions.

Comment: There are many different functions that satisfy these requirements. Why not just use $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x - 1 & \text{if } x < L+1 \\ L & \text{if } x \geq L+1 \end{cases}$$ ?

Comment: f(x) then doesn't approach $L$ asymptotically

Comment: Sure it does. Do you also need $f(x) \neq L$ for all $x$?

Comment: Yes! Is there a way I can make this happen?